# Chart.js (Customising tool tips of a stacked bar to represent each stacked data)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, stacked-chart

I am trying to implement a customised Chart.js tooltip and and am stuck with the stacked bars displaying the same data on the tooltip for each stacked bar. I need to have different data for each tooltip of each stacked bar.

[image: Screenshot]
In the chart below for e.g. for Day 2 the stacks in the bar both display an avg value of 34. Is there anyway they can be in the same bar but have different values with the customised tooltip I am using ? Like one says 34 and the other 43 for instance

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

https://jsfiddle.net/sabSK/xt5k7gac/2/

```js
var dataBars = {
  labels: ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Morning hours",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "#dedede",
      data: [09, 11, 14, 17, 19]
    },
    {
      label: "Evening hours",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "#dddddd",
      data: [12, 13, 18, 15, 20]
    },
    {
      label: "Night hours",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
      data: [09, 11, 14, 17, 19]
    },
  ]

};


var dataJason = {
  "meth": [{
      "avg": 3,
      "sum": 33
    },
    {
      "avg": 34,
      "sum": 76
    },
    {
      "avg": 73,
      "sum": 56
    },
    {
      "avg": 9,
      "sum": 43
    },
    {
      "avg": 11,
      "sum": 12
    }
  ]
};

var avgDATA = [];
var sumDATA = [];

function techData() {
  var jdata = dataJason.meth;
  var jl = jdata.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < jl; i++) {
    avgDATA.push(dataJason.meth[i].avg);
    sumDATA.push(dataJason.meth[i].sum);
  }
}

function init() {
  techData();

  var bar = document.getElementById("bar").getContext('2d');
  var barChar = new Chart(bar, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: dataBars,
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          beforeLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
            return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ' : ' + dataset.data[tooltipItem.index] + "%";
          },
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var avg = "Avg: " + avgDATA[tooltipItem.index];
            return avg;
          },
          afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var sum = "Sum: " + sumDATA[tooltipItem.index];
            return sum;
          }
        }
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
          beginAtZero: true

        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true

        }]
      }

    }


  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  init();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chart</title>

</head>

<canvas id="bar" width="400" height="350"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `label` and `footer` [tooltip callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) and return a `string` `array` from each of them as shown below:

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {       
      label: (tooltipItem, data) => data.datasets.map(ds => ds.label + ": " + ds.data[tooltipItem.index] + "%"),
      footer: tooltipItem => [
          "Avg: " + avgDATA[tooltipItem[0].index],
          "Sum: " + sumDATA[tooltipItem[0].index]              
        ]
    }
  },
  ...
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works:

```js
var dataBars = {
  labels: ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Morning hours",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "#dedede",
      data: [9, 11, 14, 17, 19]
    },
    {
      label: "Evening hours",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "#dddddd",
      data: [12, 13, 18, 15, 20]
    },
    {
      label: "Night hours",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
      data: [9, 11, 14, 17, 19]
    }
  ]
};

var dataJason = {
  "meth": [
    { "avg": 3, "sum": 33 },
    { "avg": 34, "sum": 76 },
    { "avg": 73, "sum": 56 },
    { "avg": 9, "sum": 43 },
    { "avg": 11, "sum": 12 }
  ]
};

var avgDATA = [];
var sumDATA = [];

function techData() {
  var jdata = dataJason.meth;
  var jl = jdata.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < jl; i++) {
    avgDATA.push(dataJason.meth[i].avg);
    sumDATA.push(dataJason.meth[i].sum);
  }
}

function init() {
  techData();
  var bar = document.getElementById("bar").getContext('2d');
  var barChar = new Chart(bar, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: dataBars,
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {       
          label: (tooltipItem, data) => data.datasets.map(ds => ds.label + ": " + ds.data[tooltipItem.index] + "%"),
          footer: tooltipItem => [
              "Avg: " + avgDATA[tooltipItem[0].index],
              "Sum: " + sumDATA[tooltipItem[0].index]              
            ]
        }
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }]
      }
    }
  });
}

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar" height="120"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ..... it's a good solution but how can I make this work within the same bar as you can see for Day 1 both the stacks upon hovering give me Average of 3 and Sum 33 is it possible to have different values on the same bar like the top stack different avg and bottom stack has a different ?